# (MS ACCESS) SQL to group joined statement

Tags: ms-access-2010, jet-sql

Good Morning!

I have an MS Access split database (not using ms sql server (yet)) thats joining a couple of tables with a temp query (imaginatively called "temp"!)

```
SELECT table_CORE.[core-ID],
table_CORE.[PO],
table_CORE.[Part],
table_CORE.[Part Rev],
table_CORE.[Supplier Doc #],
table_CORE.[Sup Doc Rev],

table_DATES.[date-ID],
table_DATES.[iteration],

table_REJECTIONS.[rejection-ID],
table_REJECTIONS.[iteration],
table_REJECTIONS.[reason],
table_REJECTIONS.[details],
table_REJECTIONS.[timestamp]

FROM 
    (
        (
            table_CORE  INNER JOIN [TEMP] 
            ON table_CORE.[core-ID] = TEMP.[date-ID]
        )
        INNER JOIN [table_DATES] 
            ON TEMP.[date-ID] = table_DATES.[date-ID]
            AND TEMP.[iteration]=table_DATES.[iteration]
    ) 
    INNER JOIN table_REJECTIONS 
        ON TEMP.[date-ID] = table_REJECTIONS.[rejection-ID]
        AND TEMP.[iteration]=table_REJECTIONS.[iteration]
WHERE table_CORE.[core-ID] Like '*'
```

So ultimately, this displays a list of document rejections - which is fine, except that each document applies to multiple parts.

You can tie up PO, Part and Part Rev to collapse these rejections into a single document - the problem is I would usually do this with a GROUP BY claus...

...except the "details" field is a memo datatype, and access truncates it to 256 characters when you try the GROUP BY clause.

Any ideas how to work around this? I've tried the group clause before joining it to the rejeciton table, but I end up with the same problem (in that there are multiple rejections with the same PO, Part Number and Revision tied together) - and I'm investigating other methods, but I just can't get my head round the SQL required for it!

Many thanks!

If you need any more details, just give me a shout!

---Additional details---

Example:

```
ID      PO      Part    Rev reason  details
1       111     A1      A   error   some_details1   
2       111     A1      A   error   some_details1
3       111     A1      A   error   some_details1
4       222     A1      A   error   some_details1
6       222     A1      A   error   some_details1
7       333     B1      A   error   some_details1
8       333     B1      A   error   some_details1
9       444     B1      A   error   some_details1
10      555     C1      A   error   some_details1
```

needs to be changed to:

```
PO      Part    Rev reason  details
111     A1      A   error   some_details1   
222     A1      A   error   some_details1
333     B1      A   error   some_details1
444     B1      A   error   some_details1
555     C1      A   error   some_details1
```

Note on how the join function is working:

current items are stored in CORE, and tied up to dates with a one-to-many relationship by **core-ID>>date-ID**, which then uses iteration to get he most recent event in the part's history.

That most recent event is then joined up to the rejection list using core-**ID>>rejeciton-ID *AND* date-iteration>>rejectioniteration** to return the currently active rejections.

Comment: Why do you need to do a Group By on details field? Do you have example of your failed query and do you have example data to show what you want to get out of the query?

Comment: @dbmitch and there's the crux of the problem - we effectively have duplicate rejections that need to be grouped by PO/Part Number/Revision - and then tied to the remaining detail field - but I can't get my head round the Group BY clause for just hte PO/Part/Revision and then joining that correctly to the details field.

Will post more details shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I could cheat and get MS to write my SQL for me!

Following the advice from [AllenBrowne](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html) in the query editor (instead of working with the SQL Directly), and aggregating table_REJECTIONS.details using FIRST() instead of GROUP BY() has fixed it!

What a nuisance that was to code for though - the raw SQL for the query is shown below.

```
SELECT table_CORE.PO, 
table_CORE.Part, 
table_CORE.[Part Rev], 
table_CORE.[Supplier Doc #], 
table_CORE.[Sup Doc Rev], 
table_REJECTIONS.reason, 
First(table_REJECTIONS.details) AS details

FROM 
    (
        (
        table_CORE INNER JOIN TEMP
        ON  table_CORE.[core-ID] = TEMP.[date-ID]
        )
        INNER JOIN table_DATES 
        ON 
            (
                TEMP.[iteration] = table_DATES.[iteration]
            ) 
        AND 
            (
                TEMP.[date-ID] = table_DATES.[date-ID]
            )
    )
        INNER JOIN table_REJECTIONS 
        ON 
        (
            TEMP.[iteration] = table_REJECTIONS.[iteration]
        ) 
    AND 
        (
            TEMP.[date-ID] = table_REJECTIONS.[rejection-ID]
        )

WHERE table_CORE.[core-ID] Like '*' 
GROUP BY table_CORE.PO, 
table_CORE.Part, 
table_CORE.[Part Rev], 
table_CORE.[Supplier Doc #], 
table_CORE.[Sup Doc Rev], 
table_REJECTIONS.reason;
```